Solving utility maximization, and finding demand function
A consumer has the following utility function
$$u(x_1,x_2)=2x_1x_2+x_1+2x_2$$
I want to maximize his utility function.
$$max: 2x_1x_2+x_1+2x_2.    uc:p_1x_1+p_2x_2=y_A$$
Using Lagrange, I get
$$L(x_1,x_2,\lambda)=2x_1x_2+x_1+2x_2-\lambda(p_1x_1+p_2x_2-y_A)$$
I then get the first order conditions:
$$\frac{d L}{d x_1}= 2x_2+1-\lambda p_1=0$$
$$\frac{d L}{d x_2}= 2x_1+2-\lambda p_2=0$$
$$\frac{d L}{d \lambda}= y_A-p_1x_1-p_2x_2=0$$
But I am not sure how to find the demand functions, ie. isolating $x_1$ and $x_2$. I have tried dividing the first two terms with each other, but I am pretty much stuck at this point, and would greatly appreciate a hint in how to proceed
EDIT:
I have solved it thanks to a hint I received on this website, but I have one final question: My TA told me that it was important that I remember that this utility function is quasi-concave, but I don't understand why he would tell me that? Considering that my only task is to maximize utility and find the demand function.

There are three unknowns $(x_1, x_2, \lambda)$ and three equations so there are many ways to solve this. One way is to use the first two equations to eliminate $\lambda$. Then you have two equations left that only uses the variables $x_1$ and $x_2$.

This is done by setting (1) and (2) equal to each other, right? And then solving for ?

I have solved it, but I have one final question: My TA told me that it was important that I remember that the utility function is quasi-concave, but I don't understand why he would tell me that? Considering that my only task is to maximize utility and find the demand function.

Quadi-concavity of the utility function (and linearity of the constraint) is a sufficient condition such that the first order conditions determine a global maximum. If the objective function is not quasi-concave, the solution that satisfies the first order conditions might not solve your utility maximization problem.

Check that the following utility function also represents the same preference as the one in the question:
$u(x_1,x_2)=(x_1+1)(2x_2+1)$
Solving
$\max_{(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2_+} (x_1+1)(2x_2+1)$ subject to $p_1x_1+p_2x_2\leq M$
we get
\begin{eqnarray*} (x_1^d,x_2^d)(p_1,p_2,M)=\begin{cases}\left(0,\dfrac{M}{p_2}\right) & \text{if } \dfrac{M}{p_2}+\dfrac{1}{2}<\dfrac{p_1}{p_2} \\ \left(\dfrac{M}{p_1},0\right) & \text{if } \dfrac{1}{2\left(\dfrac{M}{p_1}+1\right)}>\dfrac{p_1}{p_2} \\ \left(\dfrac{M}{2p_1}-\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{p_2}{4p_1},\dfrac{M}{2p_2}-\dfrac{1}{4}+\dfrac{p_1}{2p_2}\right)& \text{if } \dfrac{1}{2\left(\dfrac{M}{p_1}+1\right)}\leq \dfrac{p_1}{p_2}\leq \dfrac{M}{p_2}+\dfrac{1}{2}\end{cases} \end{eqnarray*}
